# Calling a function into an other function in C

Tags: c, function, return

I have a function to verify is the number is an integer, then I am trying to call this function to another that verifies if the number is on the limit. First it does not return the value and it returns to scan an integer, how do I fix that? and then it does matter the value I enter, 10 is always iVal. Why?

```
 printf("Enter an integer between 10 and 20: ");
       iVal = getIntLimited(10, 20);

       printf("Your entered %d\n", iVal);

void flushKeyboard(void){
   char enter;
   do{
      scanf("%c", &enter);
   } while (enter != '\n');

}

int getInt(void){
   int  value;
   char nl;

   do{
      scanf("%d%c", &value, &nl);

      if (nl != '\n'){
         flushKeyboard();
         printf("Invalid integer, please try again: ");
         return value;      
      }

   } while (nl != '\n');
}

int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit){

   int iVal;
   getInt() == iVal;

   if ((getInt() > lowerLimit) && (getInt() < upperLimit)){
      return iVal;
   }
   else{
   printf("Invalid value, %d < value > %d: ", lowerLimit, upperLimit);
   printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: Read [mcve] and update the question with a fully working example the reproduces your problem and that can be cut and pasted for people to test.

Comment: @E.G.  You forgot to write return value; in the first function. And you should declare a variable in the second function that gets the return value of the first function. For example int value = getInt();

Comment: I tried with and does not work. Btw I forgot to mention another function.

void flushKeyboard(void){
   char enter;
   do{
      scanf("%c", &enter);
   } while (enter != '\n');

}

Comment: It's undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarkTolonen how to reduces the code? there are 3 functions, I first forgot the first one. Now I think it's okay right?

Comment: the whole `flushKeyboard` solution is ugly, don't use `scanf` for user input, use `fgets`or `fgetc`instead and then you can use `sscanf` or `atoi` or `strtol` to parse it. When using `fgets` you don't have to write workarounds for "flushing" the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by [Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow), you need to assign the input to a variable and return it.

Your `getInt()` function should be something like:

```
int getInt(){
    int value;
    char nl;
    do{
        scanf("%d%c", &value, &nl);
        if (nl != '\n'){
            flushKeyboard();
            printf("Invalid integer, please try again: "); 
        }
    }while (nl != '\n');
    return value; //now you're returning the last scanned valid value!
}
```

Also, you're calling your `getInt()`function three times:

1st) When you "enter" your `getIntLimited()` function.

2nd) When you test `getInt() > lowerLimit`

3rd) When you test `getInt() < upperLimit`

Since the parameters `lowerLimit` and `upperLimit` are already passed to the function `getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)`, you don't need to get a value for them. So, I'd change your `getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)` function to:

```
int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit){
    int value;
    value = getInt(); //assign the input value to a variable
    if(value > lowerLimit && value < upperLimit){
        return value; //now you're returning the value that you got on getInt()
    }
    else{
        printf("Invalid value, %d < %d > %d: ", lowerLimit, value, upperLimit);
        printf("\n");
   }
   return value; //now you're able to check for this value on the first printf: printf("Your entered %d\n", iVal);
}
```

Comment: btw, there's a far more elegant way to return `value` on `int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)`, but I'll leave it up to you.

Comment: Okay you were right. My problem here was returning the values and calling a function thousand times. It is working now.

Btw I'd like to see the elegant way. But for now I will leave like because I wrote it.

Comment: @E.G. just think about it: you'll return your value either way on `int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)`. The only difference is that if the input value isn't between the limits you're going to display a message. So, why don't you do something like: if the input value is not between the limits, I'll display the message, then return the value, otherwise just return the value.

Comment: Ohhhhh, got it! I see what you're saying. I've changed it. huahuahua thanks!

Comment: @E.G. glad I helped :) . Don't forget to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this way work for you

```
void flushKeyboard(void){
   char enter;
   do{
      scanf("%c", &enter);
   } while (enter != '\n');

}

int getInt(void){

   int  value;

   scanf("%d", &value);
   return value;
}


int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit){

   int iVal;
   iVal = getInt();
   printf(" %d \n", iVal);

   if ( ( iVal > lowerLimit ) && ( iVal < upperLimit )){
      printf("OK in bound\n"); 
      return iVal;
   }

   else{

        printf("Invalid value, %d < value > %d: ", lowerLimit, upperLimit);
        printf("\n");
        exit(0);
    }

}


int main()
{

   printf("Enter an integer between 10 and 20: ");
   int iVal = getIntLimited(10, 20);

   printf("Your entered %d\n", iVal);

}
```

Also you can use woz (above post) for `getInt()` and code functionality doesn't change.